# Unity using prefabs in child nodelist results in doubling the elements I want

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am new to Unity and have followed a tutorial to establish a way of building a path for a boardgame using this code:

Route.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Route : MonoBehaviour
{
    Transform[] childObjects;
    public List<Transform> childNodeList = new List<Transform>();

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        FillNodes();
    }

    #if UNITY_EDITOR
    void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.green;

        FillNodes();

        for (int i = 0; i < childNodeList.Count; i++)
        {
            Vector3 currentPos = childNodeList[i].position;
            if (i > 0)
            {
                Vector3 prevPos = childNodeList[i - 1].position;
                Gizmos.DrawLine(prevPos, currentPos);
            }

        }
    }
    #endif

    void FillNodes()
    {
        childNodeList.Clear();

        childObjects = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

        foreach(Transform child in childObjects)
        {
            if(child != this.transform)
            {
                childNodeList.Add(child);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The script is attached to my Board GameObject which itself contains a set of duplicate prefabs:

[image]

which results in 16 elements in my child node list:

[image]

Thing is, this means that when I roll the dice, my pawn moves only half the amount of spaces it should because each space has 2 elements in the same location.

I only want to see 8 elements in my child node list, one element per tile. In other words, I only want to list the parent named Tile (x) and ignore the Cube-visual.

I know enough to know that the FillNodes() function needs to be modified, but I don't know how or what to change.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to add the `Tile` tag to the tile prefab, and add the corresponding condition. The condition in the `FillNodes` function will look like this:

```
if(child.tag == "Tile")
{
    childNodeList.Add(child);
}
```

I don't have a chance to check the code right now, so tell me if the solution doesn't work.